# Beveling Both Sides of an Edge To Create a Half-Round Not Aligning

Tags: modeling, bevel

Working to add a half-round border around the edge of an dynamic shaped piece of armor and finding it difficult to complete.

I have:

1. Duplicated the armor onto a new mesh
2. Inset a new loop to the width of the detail
3. Extruded the new faces outward
4. Beveled both sides of the extrusion with the same offset and number of faces

The result is leading to some strange corners and the bevels also don't align evenly across the armors surface.

[image]

[image]

I this just a matter of manual clean-up? Or is there a better way to achieve this with another method?